# Formal guidelines to follow when maximising the accessibility of software for people with disabilities

Tags: accessibility

Are there formal guidelines for the development of software that help minimise health risk from software, covering issues (mainly related to GUI design) such as:

- How to minimise RSI
- Minimising risks to people with color blindness
- Considering the effects software might have on causing various nervous system related conditions (e.g. epilepsy)

This sort of stuff in general?

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point is the [ADA website](http://www.ada.gov/).

See also [IBM's accessibility site](http://www-03.ibm.com/able/access_ibm/disability.html).

Answer (score 1):

See [Section 508](http://www.section508.gov) for information on accessible software. This does cover things like maximum blinking/refresh rates that could cause issues with epilepsy. For an example of a form venders can use to judge there 508 compliance and by association general  accessibility see
http://www.itic.org/index.php?src=gendocs&ref=vpat&category=resources
While following section 508 guidelines does not guarantee software will be accessible to all users since it does not cover what technologies each assistive technology product such as [Jaws](http://freedomscientific.com/products/fs/jaws-product-page.asp) or [NVDA](http://www.nvda-project.org) supports it’s a good start